# How can I load a custom stylesheet in Wordpress for custom post types?

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type, and I would like to only load a stylesheet for that custom post type.

I tried to load this from the template view for the custom post type. So I tried putting it in single-joiner.php.  Also, I tried putting it in functions.php.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style-joiner', get_template_directory() . '/style-joiner.css' );
```

Essentially, I have a variety of custom post types, and I want to run a different stylesheet for each one. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you're using the default action hook for enqueuing files, [`wp_enqueue_scripts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts), you should have access to the global `$post` and all of it's attributes.

Inside of your enqueuing function, you should be able to check the current post type either by making use of the [`is_singular()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) function, or referencing the global `$post->post_type` value.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_frontend_assets', 10 );
function enqueue_frontend_assets(){
    if( is_singular( 'joiner' ) ){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style-joiner', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style-joiner.css' );
    }
}
```

You could take it a step further and check the current post type, check to see if a `style-{post_type}.css` file exists, and then enqueue if it does - but if you just have the one post type, the above function should be enough to get you started.

**edit:** I apologize, I didn't notice before, but you're using the [`get_template_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) function. That's returning a *absolute system path*, not the URI. You'll want to use the [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) or [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) functions to return the URI instead.

Comment: I tried using that exact code just now in the functions.php file, and the single-joiner.php file.  It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I've updated the code - I didn't realize you were using the wrong function. Check out the edit - there's a difference between the `get_template_directory()` and `get_template_directory_uri()` functions - The former returns the path: `/home/usr/client/public_html/wp-content/themes/parent/`, the latter returns the URI: `https://example.com/wp-content/themes/parent/`. Also you'll want to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` if you're using a child theme, as those functions return the child theme's directory, while the `template` functions use the parent them's directory.